# How to sort angles in the range 0 to +Pi to -Pi to 0 as a linear range?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, geometry, range, angle

I am trying to solve a problem of sorting angles in the range of 0 to +Pi radians and +Pi to -Pi to 0 radians as one continuous range. I know this might be difficult to understand. Let me quote an example below.

The following are examples of the final range I would like to get after sorting a list of jumbled angles:

```
Example Inputs
Case - 1: Pi/4, 0, Pi/2, -Pi/20, Pi, -Pi/4, -Pi, -3*Pi/4, 3*Pi/4, -Pi/2, -Pi/10
Case - 2: -Pi/20, Pi/2, Pi, -Pi/2, -Pi/10, -Pi/4, Pi/4, 0,-Pi, -3*Pi/4, 3*Pi/4

Expected Output
0, Pi/4, Pi/2, 3*Pi/4, Pi, -Pi, -3*Pi/4, -Pi/2, -Pi/4, -Pi/10, -Pi/20
```

As you can see in the above list (Expected Output), the sorted list basically represents a continuous range of angles in a circle (starting from 0, making a full 360 degree rotation and ending at 0).

It is easy to sort these numbers if they are simply in a range of 0 to 360. But it gets trickier when the range is split into positive and negative angles like this.

**Extra Info:**
For some kind of strange performance reasons, I am not allowed to do the conversion of this angle into the range 0 to 2Pi for sorting. The range has to be preserved while sorting. My first solution was to convert it into 2pi range using (theta + 2pi) % (2*pi). But that solution got rejected. So I am now stuck trying to figure out how can I sort this without converting it into a different range

Comment: and special-case +/- PI, since apparently they're different for OP.

Comment: "I am not allowed" say's who? What *are* you "allowed" to do? You need to clearly state your requirements.

Comment: So +Pi and -Pi are both the same numbers essentially. But they may exist as the two different forms in the input list. So they can exist next to each other in any order in the sorted list or they can get converted into one unified representation (either +Pi or -Pi)

Comment: Convert to degrees [0, 360] by multiplying by 180/pi. If negative, you will need to add 360. Then convert back to radians.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom compare function and pass it to `sort`/`sorted` using `functools.cmp_to_key`:

```py
def angle_compare(a, b):
     def cmp(a, b):
         return (a > b) - (b > a)

     if (a < 0) == (b < 0):  # both positive or both negative
         return cmp(a, b)
     return cmp(b, a)
```

```
>>> Pi = 3.14
>>> l1 = [Pi/4, 0, Pi/2, -Pi/20, Pi, -Pi/4, -Pi, -3*Pi/4, 3*Pi/4, -Pi/2, -Pi/10]
>>> sorted(l1, key=functools.cmp_to_key(angle_compare))
[0, 0.785, 1.57, 2.355, 3.14, -3.14, -2.355, -1.57, -0.785, -0.314, -0.157]
```

Comment: This algorithm fails for the following three test cases:
[0.24497866312686414, 0.3217505543966422, -0.3217505543966422, -0.24497866312686414];
[0.06656816377582381, 0.10308160852270024, -1.6738779353175968, -1.6373644905707205];
[1.7650373229763006, 1.7841649689467045, -0.16977827396833844, -0.15160548743827282]

Comment: @ArunKumar Those lists are all correctly sorted according to your criteria. The positive values are sorted in ascending order followed by the negative values which are also sorted in ascending order (from -pi -> 0).

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import * 
a  = np.array([-pi/4.,0,pi/2., -pi/20., pi, -pi/4., -pi, -3*pi/4., 3*pi/4., -pi/2., -pi/10.])
b = a*180.0/pi
for i, val in enumerate(b):
  if val < 0: b[i] += 360
c = np.sort(b)
d = c* pi / 180.
for i in range(len(d)):
   if d[i] > pi: d[i] -= 2*pi
```